# Populate Spinner with Unique values from Json Android

Tags: android, json, duplicates, spinner

I am populating an spinner from json response, it is working but with duplicate values. I am trying to remove the duplicate values with below code but still showing the duplicate values

```
ArrayList<String> BookCategoryName1;

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
if(jsonObject.getInt("success")==1){
        
   JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("category");
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
     JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String bookcat_name=jsonObject1.getString("Year");

         if(BookCategoryName1.contains(bookcat_name)){

         }else{
             //Add value here..
             BookCategoryName1.add(bookcat_name);
         }
```

}
}

Any suggestion pls

Comment: May I know why you didnt use `equal` instead `contains` ?

Comment: tried with equal too but same result

Comment: equal and with uppercase() ? did try this laready ?

Comment: tried with uppercase too no luck